# Why does this code only return the last object from the dictionary?

Tags: c#, object, dictionary

I have created a class with a few items. and create a dictionary object value from it.
The adding items to the dictionary appears to work fine when I look at it in debug mode.
yet when I try to retrieve the objects I only get the last object in the dictionary. yet I can retrieve all the keys.
Am I missing some simple step here?

```
public class Block 
{
    public int blockID16 { get; set; }
    public int blockID {get; set;}
    public string blockName {get; set;}
    public int instance {get;set;}
}

// init object and dictionary
Block block = new Block();
Dictionary<int, Block> blockDict = new Dictionary<int, Block>();

// read an xml file and write to the dictionary   
blockDict.Add(block.blockID16, block);

// I then return the dictionary from a called method below and read it.
Dictionary<int, Block> blockDict = new Dictionary<int, Block>();
blockDict = XMLreader.Reader();

Block block1 = new Block();
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Block> entry in blockDict)
{
    block1.blockID16 = entry.Value.blockID16;
    block1.blockName=entry.Value.blockName;
    block1.instance = entry.Value.instance;
    block1.blockID = entry.Value.blockID;

    keyValue = entry.Key;
}
```

Comment: Create your `Block` in the loop. You are using the same instance of it.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the details of the code that adds your block to the dictionary

Comment: What do you end up doing with `block` besides setting it's values?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Assuming that the loop works, all you're doing is looping and assigning it to block1 but you're not actually doing anything with it.

Comment: Dude you miss the method Add inside the foreach? LOL

Comment: Well I am creating a lookup dictionary to retrieve the objects based on the key. I did notice a strange thing happening that may be related somehow... Using a debug break just after I write each entry to the dictionary and looking at the local I notice that  when I start adding to the dictionary everything looks good till I get to about 80 entries... then everytime I add a new item.. all the items in the dictionary change to the the last item... very strange.   Oh this is the line that adds the block to the dictionary

Comment: blockDict.Add(block.blockID16, block);

Comment: The loop is only to retrieve the data from the dictionary, not add to it.

Comment: You only have one block.  You keep changing the values of the same block over and over and then insert the reference in your dictionary so that your dictionary is filled with many references to the one block.

Comment: Yes Chris.. you are correct... I was using the same reference in the loop and never looked back at the previous entries. I've only been programming c# a few weeks and didn't think of the instance as a reference to an object ( NOT a variable )  Thanks everyone. this does work with a new instance in the writing loop. Can't learn if you don't make mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Yes Chris, I was indeed using the object over and over again without re instancing it. Thanks, I am still learning and have been programming only a few weeks and confused the object reference with a variable value. Works fine now. This was just a test to help me lean how to add objects to the dictionary before I move to the bigger project. Thanks everyone.